# Best Practices for Verifying Ownership of an NFT ERC-721 Token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am developing a Smart Contract (SC) and a front-end Dapp which will be used to sell some NFT ERC-721 tokens. When a user/address buys one of the NFT tokens, the token will be minted to his benefit by the SC, while my Dapp will register the said purchase in a local database. Considering that a user could potentially sell his token at a later date without going through my front-end Dapp, what is the best practice to synchronise the token ownership for a specific user, found in the SC with my local database? Should I query the SC every time the user accesses the site and wishes to display his tokens owned in the front-end Dapp? Wouldn't this take too long? Should I query the SC only if the user tries to sell one of his tokens in order to verify if he is the legitimate owner?

Answer (score 1):

You need to track `Transfer` events of the NFT token smart contract by scanning all new blocks in Ethereum blockchain. When you detect a transfer event, a worker process updates your local database.

Comment: I know you can use scanner websites to check the events. Can this be done programmatically? Also, can we check the smartcontract address used to mint the NFT? I can't find any reference on how to do this programmatically?

Comment: It can be done only programmatically. I suggest you first start by how Solidity and events work, then explore client libraries like web3.js or web3.py and then proceed to write your own application for this.